# Where does the Git documentation mention that "git-foo" on $PATH can be called as "git foo"?

Tags: git, manual

Git has this feature, where you can place any executable named `git-foo` on `$PATH` and then call it as `git foo <args>`, like a built-in subcommand (or is it more of a side-effect of how Git implemented subcommands in the early days?).

I learned this probably 15 years ago and now told someone about this who didn't know it already. I'd like to point them to some documentation explaining it in a bit more detail (e.g. the variables that are placed in the environment) by `git`.

Where is this behavior documented in the official documentation (or e.g. in a mail thread by the developers)?

Comment: It's probably related to how git handles aliasing? Maybe also related to things like `man git-diff`?

Comment: Yes, I think the convention of putting the man page under `git-diff` began when you could still call `git diff` as `git-diff` (which doesn't work anymore today).

Comment: it is at least mentioned [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---list-cmdsgroupgroup82308203) ... :D

Comment: Yeah, what @LeGEC linked is the only place that I found in the official docs which even acknowledges that this works under `list-cmds` it mentions "others (all other commands in `$PATH` that have git- prefix)"

Comment: It mentions "the non-dashed form of Git commands" in https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitcli. But it does not give more details on "dashed form of Git commands". And `git-foo` like `git-log` is not valid now.

Comment: @LeGEC Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @Guildenstern I was hoping that someone would point to some more assertive source -- not a side note to an option marked "experimental" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place I know of in the documentation is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---list-cmdsgroupgroup82308203) (`git help git`, `--list-cmds` option, emphasis mine) :

> --list-cmds=group[,group…]
>
> List commands by group.
> This is an internal/experimental option and may change or be removed in the future. Supported groups are: builtins, parseopt (builtin commands that use parse-options), main (all commands in libexec directory), **others (all other commands in $PATH that have `git-` prefix)**, `list-<category>` (see categories in command-list.txt), nohelpers (exclude helper commands), alias and config (retrieve command list from config variable completion.commands)

Comment: Yes, it _kind of_ hints at the fact that anything on `$PATH` called `git-<foo>` is considered a "git command" and thus can maybe be called as `git foo`, but it doesn't say it out loud. :D I think this comes closest to answering my original question.  Thank you for the answer!